# What are exactly static and dynamic libraries

Tags: libraries

Is it possible for someone to explain in detail the actual difference between static and dynamic libraries? What are the advantages and disadvantages for each?

Answer (score 0):

Static libraries are included in your program with exact offsets into the library. Simlified pseudocode example might be:

```
open_lib("foo.so")
add_arg(0, "arg1")
add_arg(1, "arg2")
execute_stuff_at_lib_location(0x34235)
```

Dynamic libraries use a table to get the offset of the function:

```
open_lib("foo.so")
offset = get_function_offset("do_all_the_things")
add_arg(0, "arg1")
add_arg(1, "arg2")
execute_stuff_at_lib_location(offset)
```

Dynamic linking is almost always better since a small change in the static linking can render your code unusable. On the other hand, by using static linking, the code is marginally faster.

Edit: on some systems, the static library is included with the program so each app has their own copy instead of using one DLL for the whole system.

Comment: Not “on some systems”; static libraries are _always_ duplicated when used. Sometimes that's even useful…